# Javascript Promises recall until acceptable return

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

ES6

I want to keep calling this method until it returns 0 as the result. Sometimes it takes 5 seconds to return a value, sometimes it takes 10 seconds. Sometimes it doesnt return the value but i want to keep going until it returns 0. It should wait until the answer has come back or timeout in 10 seconds to recall it.

This is how i tried this, but it is not working for some reason.

```
 function method() {
        doSomething(from_api).then(function (status) {
            if(status != "0") {
                method();
            } else {
                console.log("success");
            }
        }), function (error) {
            method();
        });
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, i edited this now. This is call to api.

Comment: I think you need to add a bit of context - sounds wrong to me to keep hitting an api until it returns something you want - is something else touching the api to allow it to return what you're waiting for?

Comment: Please post the `getStatus()` method also

Comment: well, that will log "success" to the console once the status is 0 ... other than that, it's pretty useless to whatever originally called it - some "returns" here and there would probably help if you want the original call to method to have a clue when the call succeeds - e.g. return getStatus, and return method ... now whatever originally called method gets a promise that resolves when there's success

Comment: @VladNeacsu -  really? it's something that returns a promise that resolves to a status - I don't think it's important to the question at all

Comment: getStatus() is a method from Real-time physical application that has been give command to do something. I think i chose bad name for this example. doSomething() would be better

Comment: @Chopter The paranthesis in the code above doesn't match. Is it a typo or is it how u originally write it in your code?

Comment: What exactly "is not working"? Of course `method` itself doesn't `return` anything useful, which is a problem, but it should be called repeatedly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like an asynchronous-while-loop.

```
function asynchronous_while(promise_provider, condition) {
    return promise_provider().then(function (result) {
        if (condition(result) === true) {
            return asynchronous_while(promise_provider, condition);
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    });
}

asynchronous_while(function () {  // promise provider
    return getStatus(from_api);
}, function (result) {            // condition
    return result != "0";
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log("success", result);
    // result should now be "0";
});
```

How long it takes to complete depends entirely on when `getStatus(from_api)` returns `0`. That might be *never*. The same pitfalls of a traditional *while* apply.

Comment: It takes some time to get return from the method. Since this is a method call that does something in real life and it might timeout. I think this can't be done asynchronously.

Comment: Sounds like you should look at push/pull notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. You just had an extra closing parenthesis.
Change:

```
}), function (error) {
```

to:

```
}, function (error) {
```